# Allow a list of IP addresses to access ports with UFW

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I want to allow a list of (around 100) IP addresses to access a website on an ubuntu server.  I'd like to be able to refresh the list via cron.

I'm trying to do it with UFW. I thought this might be easier to do via an app profile. Is this the best approach?

```
[My App]
  title = "My Web"
  description = "Allows to access web"
  ports = 80/tcp|443/tcp
```

How can I add the list of allowed IP's?  I want to add something like this to the profile:

```
  ips=[/var/www/allowed_ips.txt]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application profiles describe applications. Each contains a title, a description and a set of ports to connect to. They do not describe rules to allow or deny access to such applications. This is done separately. E.g.

```sh
ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/16 to any app "MyWeb"
```

If you want to keep a list of IP addresses in a file, as you suggest in the question, I'd suggest that you add a shell script like the one below to your crontab. It will first delete all rules for your application (see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/930830/299224)), then add rules for the IPs in your file.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

APPNAME="MyWeb"
IPFILE=/var/www/allowed_ips.txt

RULES_DESC=$(ufw status numbered | grep "$APPNAME" \
  | awk -F"[][]" '{print $2}' | tr --delete [:blank:] | sort -rn)
for NUM in $RULES_DESC; do
  yes | ufw delete $NUM
done

for IP in $(cat $IPFILE); do
  ufw allow from $IP to any app "$APPNAME"
done
```

You will probably want to suppress the output from the script in your crontab.

Comment: thanks @nickie that looks perfect.

Comment: tested this today, works well.

Comment: finally, THANK YOU. it works PERFECT